# Cannot connect to internet or even local network

Tags: windows-xp, internet

I'm trying to setup a mini-desktop and have officially run out of ideas on how to get the internet working on it.  Here are the specs with newegg links:

Windows XP Home 32-bit
[AMD Athlon II X3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103886)
[ZOTAC GF6100-E-E AM3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813500045)
[2GB DDR2 ram](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148235)
[250GB WD HDD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136771)

First attempt was to get ethernet working.  It did not work after plugging it in, so I tried installing drivers via the disk that came with the motherboard.  Still did not work, so I [downloaded drivers from the manufacturer](http://www.zotac.com/support/download.html) (you can either get the HD audio or chipset which is all the drivers in one package).  Uninstalled the old drivers, restart, install new drivers.  Still not working.

Perhaps it is not the machine?  I unplug the cable from the back of the mini-desktop and into a different PC (laptop running Windows 8.1) and the connection works just fine.

"Screw it!" I say, as I get a wireless adapter.  Plug in the USB wireless adapter (802.11n SMC networks model SMCWUSB-N2), unknown device.  Try the adapter in a Windows 7 desktop, works fine.  Download those [drivers from the manufacturer](http://www.smc.com/en-global/download/index?search=1&main=29&sub=34&model=0&keyword=SMCWUSB-N2) and install them.  Still nothing.

As it stands now, the Local Area Connection and Wireless Network Connection have the red X.  When running `ipconfig /all` it returns:

> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Host Name............:minitardis
>   Primary Dns Suffix.......:
>   Node Type............:Broadcast
>   IP Routing Enabled:........: Yes
>   WINS Proxy Enabled:........: Yes
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
>
> Media State...........:Media disconnected
>      Description...........:NVIDIA nForce 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet #2
>      Physical Address.........:00-01-2E-35-45-25
>
> Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:
>
> Media State...........:Media disconnected
>      Description...........:SMCWUSB-N2 802.11n Wireless USB 2.0 Adapter
>      Physical Address.........:00-22-2D-C0-08-9D

I am at a loss and cannot figure out where to go from here.  Any ideas?

**Update**

Tried to update the BIOS, still nothing.  In fact, I updated so many drivers, Windows XP decided I need to re-authenticate it, claiming the hardware is too different from initial setup.

**Update 2**

As luck would have it, Windows XP created an infinite loop that left me unable to get into my machine.  Upon startup, a pop-up said Windows needed to be reactivated, would I like to do this now?  I click "Yes" it does a pseudo-login and says it is already authenticated, only option being "OK".  It then logs out and goes to User profiles screen.  Had I clicked "No" at the first menu, I also end up at user profile screen.

So, I reboot, mash `F8` and Safe Mode w/ cmd.  It gets me in!  Do `explorer.exe` and get a desktop!  Then I notice my ethernet port has a light shining!  Open browser, nothing.  `ipconfig /all`, "An internal error occurred: the request is not supported (Additional information: Unable to query host name).

Reinstalled the OS, still not working.  Plugged in WiFi adapter, manually installed drivers, and the WiFi works now.  Would still like to get Ethernet working though.

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 and ping your gateway IP address. Results?

Comment: Now, the other thing is, perhaps your router is configured for distributing static IP's on your LAN, rather than via DHCP. I doubt this, but it's a possibility. Do you know anything of that? Because, you could connect that Ethernet cable to another PC, and the other PC could work because it's been previously configured with a static IP. Your desktop, on the other hand, has not. It could be set-up for automatic configuration via DHCP, which is why it's not working (because your router is not set-up for that). So, I guess the question is, who configured the network?

Comment: `ping 127.0.0.1` send 4 and receives 4, each time<1ms.  Ping the router and it says `Destination host unreachable`

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 the router uses DHCP

Comment: Do any LED's illuminate on the RJ-45 (Ethernet) port on the back of the motherboard/ PC?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 no lights for the Ethernet but the adapter flashes green

Comment: Okay, so, um, where did you find the driver? Because I searched for 64-bit XP drivers for that mobo on Zotac's website, and I only found an audio and chipset driver. No Ethernet/ NIC driver.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 It is 32-bit XP but the chipset drivers come as a bundled package including ethernet, audio, display, and a few others.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant 32-bit, but you answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, try turning off router, modem, and your desktop, then restarting, modem, router, and then your desktop in that order.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Sorry for the delay.  I just tried your suggestion and still nothing.

Comment: Can you post entire output from ipconfig /all?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Updated question

Comment: Does the Device Manager say anything interesting about your network devices?

Comment: @jdigital Not from what I can tell.  No yellow markings.  Is there something I should look for in the properties or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer model from [this list](http://www.nvidia.com/page/gpu_mobo.html) is apparently the model
"NVIDIA GeForce 6150 GPU and NVIDIA nForce 430 MCP featuring HD video".

You might try downloading the latest driver for the nForce 430 MCP,
which is apparently [version 15.26](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/9701/en-us) from 2009.3.16.

From the few packages I have looked at on the ZOTAC download page
(where it is quite unclear how to find your exact model),
I have seen that this driver is missing for some downloads.

Comment: Still no connection.  No problems running through this installation.

Comment: You might think of doing a [Repair Install](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Windows-XP-%22Repair-Install%22).

Comment: I just did a fresh install and reformatted the hard drive as well

Comment: Does Ethernet work?

Comment: No.  I also tried Upgrading to Service Pack 3 (no problems) but still no luck.

Comment: If WiFi is working but not Ethernet, there's also the possibility of a hardware problem. Maybe you could try the network adapter in another computer.

Comment: So test that the WiFi also works in a different computer?  I don't see how that would help.  At first I thought maybe the motherboard had a faulty connection or something but I can see the light indicating the cable is plugged in when the computer is booting up.  After XP starts, the light turns off and the port acts as though nothing is plugged in.  However, when booting into Safe Mode w/ cmd the light remains on even after XP is running.  I am unfamiliar with this, but **Update 2** gives details.

Comment: I am confused: WiFi was supposed to be working after the reinstall, and Ethernet I thought was broken. If Ethernet is working when booting in Safe Mode with Network then some installed program is the cause.

Comment: I haven't tried Safe Mode w/ Network.  I tried Safe Mode w/ Command terminal.  Ethernet was not *working* per-se, but the light indicating the cord is plugged into the computer was lit (which it is not lit when starting XP normally).

Comment: Networking and Internet works in Safe Mode with Network, but is disabled in all the other modes.

Comment: Tried starting into safe mode with networking and nothing. Indicator light turns off on startup of windows.

Comment: You have done everything possible regarding software/drivers/OS without success. This only leaves hardware, but trying your network adapter on another computer is, I believe, not possible since it's built into the motherboard. My conclusion (which I hope is wrong) is that the Ethernet adapter is broken and repairing is probably impossible (or not worth it). As a last-gasp test and before giving up on it, try booting a Linux Live CD and see if it can do better.

Comment: I appreciate all your suggestions.  Unfortunately, a Linux Live USB booting (Ubuntu 13) did not pick up the Ethernet cable either.

Comment: Then this leaves only hardware as the cause of the problem. To use Ethernet you will need to add an external network adapter, since the built-in one looks to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

The state means there is no media - when you plug the cable in it should change to trying get an ip address - if DHCP is not found it would get the internal self-assigned IP
so let's try this:

1) Plug in the ethernet - does it try to get IP? if not and the media state is still disconnected it means the card cannot establish the link

in that case open the HW properties for the card and try to match your switch/router settings i.e. speed set to 100 and duplex set instead of the default auto values

2) in case it does try to get an IP and fails you need to look into your dhcp server settings or the IP settings for that card and verify it doesn't have static IP set

Comment: Tried every speed/duplex option and still nothing.  Ethernet was plugged in the whole time but unplugging and reconnecting did not do anything.

Comment: @TomEus. In nr 2's case it will most likely get a 169.x.x.x IP

Comment: David did the media state change when you plug the cable in? Also do you see the network card trying to establish the connection (flashing)

Comment: @TomEus no it is still marked as `Media diconnected`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing with the NIC settings in the BIOS? If they are available, it usually has ENABLE, DISABLE, and ENABLE with boot. Try playing with them to see if it makes any difference.
Another thought is disable the firewall if is on. Also if you have antivirus or internet suite on, try disabling.

Comment: Firewall is off, all antivirus stuff is off.  I looked through every BIOS setting and have nothing for "NIC".  Only networks-like settings I found are: MAC Lan (Disabled, *Auto*), MAC Media Interface (*Pin Strap*, MII, RGMII), and PCI LAN boot ROM (Enabled, *Disabled*).

Answer (score 1):

Programs like firewalls, antivirus applications, VPN clients, and various malware can cause Internet/Network connection problems. You may try the following to reset TCP/IP, Windows Socket, and Windows Firewall.

1. Click Start, then select Run.
2. Type "command" and press enter.
3. Type the following commands, pressing Enter after each command:

   **netsh int ip reset reset.txt**

   **netsh winsock reset**

   **netsh firewall reset**
4. Restart the computer. This should help.

Comment: The 3 commands ran fine, but nothing is fixed after restart.

Comment: Try also to resetting your router to default settings.

Comment: Router is on default settings